# How to place notes from different source sheet in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling trying to find a method to place information from a cell (a range of cells) as comments in a different cell (range of cell) in a different sheet.

Something like this, if I have Apple in Cell A1 in Sheet1 I want Apple to be inserted as a comment in Cell F1 in Sheet 2.

I tried coming up with something like this.

```
//I'm still working on this I have not been able to make this work//
//Ideally this will put the phone numbers as comment's in the needed cases//
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("report");
 var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var nrange = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 3, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), 1)
 var sourcenotes = [nrange.getValue()]
 var notes = targetsheet.getRange(2, 6, sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1)
 notes.setNotes(sourcenotes);
```

As you can read this is not working I've tried different methods but none is working so I come to you guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

The function "setNotes" takes a 2 dimension array, the value should be like this setNotes([sourcenotes]). Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes).

Also if you are going to set the note for just one cell, i would recomend to use the function setNote. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) is an example on that function.